# Проблема с отображением объемного текста в TextView

Tags: android, textview

Итак. В моем приложении есть Activity в которой всего лишь 1 TextView. В него загружается большой текст. По нажатию на правую или левую часть экрана, текст скролится на одну страницу(страница==экран) вперед или назад соответственно. Проблема в том, что после 2-го или 3-го пролистывания, первая и последняя строки начинают по немного обрезаться. Т.е. видна не вся строка, а только ее часть, а остальная часть находится на другой странице. В чем проблема понять не могу, бьюсь уже несколько дней.

вот так я скролю TextView на предыдущую страницу:

```
text.scrollBy(0, text.getHeight() - (2*(text.getHeight())))
```

а вот так на след. страницу:

```
text.scrollBy(0, text.getHeight());
```

Из ключевых настроек для TextView - это отступы: 5dp по бокам и по 2dp сверху и снизу. И расстояние между строк = 1.6

Вот парочка скринов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Есть предположение, из-за того, что ты берешь высоту контейнера текста то и смещение будет больше чем предыдущий текст. Я бы попробовал построить scroll на количестве строк, а не по высоте.

Comment: Так, а есть какие-то методы, что бы узнать количество видимых строк?

Comment: Ты прав, нет такого(( Но строка обрезается из за того, что высота больше текста. Можно конечно с коэффициентом поиграть, но это костыль костыльный. Сейчас попробую либы поискать. Кстати, по страничный скрол обязательное условие? Просто можно в скролвью обвернуть и будет норм.

Comment: Нуууу я хочу просто и обычный скролл добавить и постраничный. С коэффициентами пробовал что-то сделать, но потом понял, что если изменить шрифт, то все ломается опять. Следовательно надо какую-то закономерность искать, а это хард.

Comment: Если не принципиально написание собственного скрола, то эта либа тебе понравится https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/108#!description